# Cómo Sumar posición X de un control en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una duda, necesito hacer que varios controles se creen automáticamente y sumen su posición, por ejemplo:

```
Button b1 = new Button();
```

Necesitaría crear varios `b1` y que cada uno de estos sume su posición x por 200 a la del anterior, es decir:

`b1` tendría la posición X 200, `b2` tendría 400, `b3` 600 y así, solo que supongo debería ser una operación como suma o multiplicación, ya que son un número indefinido o variable de `b1`.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, nos puedes mostrar lo que has intentado para lograrlo? Con la propiedad `Location` y un ciclo debería ser suficiente para empezar, pero, andale, muestranos :D. Echale un vistazo al [tour] y a [ask] para que te hagas una idea de como funciona el sitio y nos traigas un [mcve] de lo que quieres lograr, con eso nos basta para encontrar tu problema y darle con todo :P

Comment: Supongo que quieres crear botones y agregarlos en línea. Yo creo que hay mejores maneras que andar calculando posiciones, por ejemplo usar un FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: Eso uso, pero los muestra de arriba a abajo

Comment: pon el flow en horizontal ;)

Answer (score -1):

B2.Location = new point ( B1.location.X*2,B1.location.Y)

Si tienen tamaños distintos lo del paréntesis es
B1.locationx*2+((numerodeletrsdeb1/numerodeletrasdeb2)/2)+1, B1.location.Y+(b2.height/2)+1

Comment: Amerita una explicación. El OP es novato y necesita guía para entender el problema y la solución que ofreces. Si puedes editar tu respuesta sería estupendo.